# Magento 2.2.2 how to check if current page is a CMS page in .phtml file?

Tags: cms-pages, object-manager, magento2.2.2

I am using the following code to check if the current page is *Product detail page*:

```
$objectManagerCms = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$registry = $objectManagerCms->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$currentProduct = $registry->registry('current_product');
if ($currentProduct) {
    // Custom code
}
```

Now how to check if current page is a CMS page?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are no registry variable add at cms page.

> **So, if you want to check a page is CMS page then you need to check current controller and action name means Full action name**

### Best practices

> **In Magento2, every block has request Object ,So you can get  current page full action name via**
>
> $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName();

### Code:

```
$currentFullAction = $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
$cmspages = array('cms_index_index','cms_page_view');
if(in_array($currentFullAction, $cmspages)){
    //CMS page
}
```

Comment: Cool, It's working! $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName();

Answer (score 7):

> Try to use below code in your .phtml file

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
$checkModule = $request->getModuleName();
if($checkModule == 'cms'){
    echo "cms page";
}else{
    echo "not cms page";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The registry class could be used in many places. Thus, it's relatively weak check. I suggest you to check full action name of request, like so:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http::getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view'
```