# How to add a category to the breadcrumbs?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, navigation, breadcrumbs

I wanted to add a static text with a link in front of my category page and product page breadcrumbs.

Existing Breadcrumbs:

**Home > Category > Sub Category > Sub Category**

How I want it to be

**Home > Static Text with link > Category > Sub Category > Sub Category**

Remember, my cms pages breadcrumbs need to remain as they are. Not like above.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make changes in the below file.

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbName ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
            <?php 
            //custom code by John
           //your customer code here, 
            if ($crumbName == "home") : ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a href="Your static link here" title="">Your static link title here</a>
                </li>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

see above and make the necessary changes in the same file. 
Note: it will be preferable if you can override this file. 
[How to override .phtml files in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/how-to-override-phtml-files-in-magento-2)
Also, change href link and title on the above code.
To check if the current page is cms page or category page
[Magento 2.2.2 how to check if current page is a CMS page in .phtml file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209258/magento-2-2-2-how-to-check-if-current-page-is-a-cms-page-in-phtml-file)